# Why isn't my request getting to the server? - Works locally not on server though

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, nginx

I've got a basic HTML website with JQuery that submits an Ajax POST request to a node server everything works fine running locally on my machine (Windows), I can submit the form in browser get the request on the server and send an appropriate response however on my VPS (droplet) nothing is getting to the POST route.. my GET '/' works well though.

**Here's my app.js**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var location = path.join(__dirname + '/../src');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config/config.json');
var port = 8080;
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static(location));
app.use(cors());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

// theTransporter will be used to send mail
var theTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: config.auth.user,
        pass: config.auth.pass
    }
});


// handle post requests for contact form
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {

    // get a copy of the newContact object
    var newContact = req.body;

    // Construct the email to be sent
    var message = "New Email from " + newContact.name + "\n";
    message += "Email Address: " + newContact.email + "\n";
    message += "Phone Number: " + newContact.phone + "\n";
    message += "Company name: " + newContact.companyname + "\n";
    message += " Industry: " + newContact.industry + "\n";
    message += "Subject: " - newContact.subject + "\n";
    message += "Message from " + newContact.name + ": \n";
    message += newContact.message;

    // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols 
    var mailOptions = {
        from: newContact.email, // sender address
        to: config.emailAddress, // reciever address
        subject: newContact.email + " - " + newContact.subject, // Subject line
        text: message
    };

    // Check if email is undefined, return complaint to client if so
    if (typeof newContact.email === "undefined" || newContact.email == "") {
        res.status(200).jsonp({
            message: "Error - No Email provided.",
            error: true,
            error_contents: "No Email Provided",
            user_generated: true
        });
        return;
    }
    // Check if phone is undefined, return complaint to client if so
    if (typeof newContact.phone === "undefined" || newContact.phone == "") {
        res.status(200).jsonp({
            message: "Error - No Phone Number provided.",
            error: true,
            error_contents: "No Phone Number Provided",
            user_generated: true
        });
        return;
    }
    // Check if message is undefined, return complaint to client if so
    if (typeof newContact.message === "undefined" || newContact.message == "") {
        res.status(200).jsonp({
            message: "Error - No Message provided.",
            error: true,
            error_contents: "No Message Provided",
            user_generated: true
        });
        return;
    }
    // Check if name is undefined, return complaint to client if so
    if (typeof newContact.name === "undefined" || newContact.name == "") {
        res.status(200).jsonp({
            message: "Error - No Name provided.",
            error: true,
            error_contents: "No Name Provided",
            user_generated: true
        });
        return;
    }
    // Check if Company Name is undefined, return complaint to client if so
    if (typeof newContact.companyname === "undefined" || newContact.companyname == "") {
        res.status(200).jsonp({
            message: "Error - No Company Name provided.",
            error: true,
            error_contents: "No Company Name Provided",
            user_generated: true
        });
        return;
    }
    // Check if Industry is undefined, return complaint to client if so
    if (typeof newContact.industry === "undefined" || newContact.industry == "") {
        res.status(200).jsonp({
            message: "Error - No Industry provided.",
            error: true,
            error_contents: "No Industry Provided",
            user_generated: true
        });
        return;
    }


    // Send the email with Transporter
    theTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {

        if (err) {
            // log the error
            console.log(err);
            // send it back to the client
            res.status(500).jsonp({
                message: "something went wrong..",
                error: true,
                error_contents: err,
                user_generated: false
            });
            return;
        } else {
            // log the good news
            console.log('Email sent succesfully to ' + mailOptions.to);
            // close transporter
            theTransporter.close();
            // send a good response back to client
            res.status(200).jsonp({
                message: "GG",
                error: false,
                error_contents: null,
                user_generated: null
            });
            return;
        }
    });
});

//  Default catch all for website
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../src/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV + ' server running at http://localhost:' + port);
})
```

and this is my request on the client...

```
frm.submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://www.localhost.ca:8080/contact",
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.err && data.user_generated) {
                        $('.output-message').text("Message not sent: " + data.error_contents);
                        $('.output-message').css("color", "red");
                    } else if (data.err) {
                        $('.output-message').text("Internal Server Error - Please try again in a couple of moments");
                        $('.output-message').css("color", "red");
                    } else {
                        $('.output-message').text("Message sent succesfully!");
                        $('.output-message').css("color", "green");

                        document.getElementById('contact-form').reset();
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    if (data.err && data.user_generated) {
                        $('.output-message').text("Message not sent: " + data.error_contents);
                        $('.output-message').css("color", "red");
                    } else if (data.err) {
                        $('.output-message').text("Internal Server Error - Please try again in a couple of moments");
                        $('.output-message').css("color", "red");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Presuming it's the server setup that caused the issue I setup a new Ubuntu Droplet and installed node, I also [used this method][1] to setup an SSL cert. I can post my Nginx configuration if it would be helpeful as well.. apart from that I'm really stumped. I've setup two droplets now and can't get a POST to work on either one.. obviously using the same faulty strategy.

The weird part is it works perfect locally so I thought it was good to go, any questions or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Here is my NGINX Configuration file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/tycoonmedia/src;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name tycoonmedia.ca www.tycoonmedia.ca;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php7.0-fpm:
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tycoonmedia.ca/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tycoonmedia.ca/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot



    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
    # if ($scheme != "https") {
    #     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    # } # managed by Certbot

}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name tycoonmedia.ca www.tycoonmedia.ca;
#
#   root /var/www/tycoonmedia/src;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


  [1]: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let
```

-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: This would be easier to diagnose with the AJAX error response.

Comment: @Chase Sorry, I should note the response is very slow and I get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error. I've tried various configurations of requests using Postman and the best I've got is it timing out.

Comment: Is your post even working? What does `curl -v -X POST -d 'somedata' http://yourserver/your/post/path` result in?

Comment: @I.R.R. I'm getting a "Moved Permanently Nginx page..

Comment: Well that narrows it down to nginx configuration then. Post your webserver config and someone much better at nginx might be able to notice what's up.

Comment: @I.R.R. will do, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this line in your proxy settings in your nginx config is causing the issue:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Remove it and reload nginx and you should be OK.